# AppHarbor: Communication between Web App and Background Worker

Tags: web-services, appharbor

I have two questions, but let me set the stage first:

Say you have a typical scenario where you have a web application and a mid-tier web service.
The web application receives a request from the user, queries the web service and sends a response to the user.

If the web service and the web application were running on the same machine, the web app would go through **localhost:port** to access the web service.

*(I do understand that AppHarbor web and background workers are not running on traditional machines but it's easier to use that metaphor)*

To make this slightly complex, the web service is actually a console app running a HTTP server and thus acting as a web service, let's call it webservice.exe.

My first question is: will AppHarbor run webservice.exe on the same machine as the web application and so enable the web application to access the web service via **localhost:port**.

If not, will the machine name where the console app is running always be static (which allows web app to reliably access **machinename:port**). If so, will the webservice.exe machine allow incoming connections from the web application machine?

My second question is if both apps run on the same machine (the localhost scenario), will external users be able to access webservice.exe via **myapp.apphb.com:port** ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppHarbor does not currently support background workers (which is where your console application would be running) attaching to ports.

If you instead decide to host the service in an ASP.NET application and run it in a web worker on AppHarbor (as a normal web site), then it would be available at myawesomeapplication.apphb.com or using a custom hostname if you decide to add one.

If the service-abstraction is not needed, you might also want to just do away with it and fold it into the main web site.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm afraid the service abstraction is needed in my case. Do you think I can use RabbitMQ (Cloud AMQP) to facilitate communication? Are background workers allowed to listen on a queue?

Comment: @tenor Absolutely, Cloud AMQP would be a great solution.